# The group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ has precisely $4$ subgroups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

True/False: The group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ has precisely $4$ subgroups.

Solution:

True, since there are $4$ divisors $1,2,5,10$ thus it has $4$ subgroups.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct.

**NOTE**: There is **exactly one** subgroup for **each** divisor as it is a property of **cyclic groups**.

**Side Note:** $A_4$, the alternating subgroup of the group of permutations of four elements ,$S_4$, has order 12 and has no subgroup of order 6

Comment: Yes, editing right-away.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

If you define $\mathbb{Z}_{10} = \mathbb{Z}/ 10\mathbb{Z}$, then this follows from the correspondence theorem: the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ correspond to the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ that contain $10\mathbb{Z}$, and there is exactly one such subgroup for each divisor of $10$.